# Finding tokens in a Smalltalk String with PetitParser

Tags: parsing, smalltalk, petitparser

I want to parse

```
'This,is,an,example,text'
```

like in findTokens

```
'This,is,an,example,text' findTokens: $, 
an OrderedCollection('This' 'is' 'an' 'example' 'text')
```

but cannot figure out how to do it with PetitParser, delimitedBy: and separatedBy: didn't helped me I tried

```
( #any asParser delimitedBy: $, asParser ) plus flatten parse:  'This,is,an,example,text'
```

but obviously not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this pattern all the time with PetitParser when I want to exclude something. Just define either "what I'm looking for" or "what I want to exclude" (whichever's easier to describe) as a parser, and then negate it, and process as necessary.

```
s := 'This,is,an,example,text'.
separator := $, asParser ==> [ :n | nil ].
token := separator negate plus flatten.
p := (token separatedBy: separator) ==> [ :nodes |
    nodes copyWithout: nil ].
p parse: s.
```

Comment: This `copyWithout:` really feels ugly... I suspect there is a way to avoid it by defining a variant of `separatedBy:` that would not add the separators to the output in the first place… Another solution could be with `foldLeft:` but as I see it it requires your own class for the collection of tokens.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `delimitedBy:` in combination with `withoutSeparators`:

```
|text parser|

text := 'This,is,an,example,text'.
parser := (#word asParser plus flatten delimitedBy: ($, asParser)) withoutSeparators.

parser parse: text
```

Seems to be a recent improvement to PetitParser.

Answer (score 2):

`a #delimitedBy: b` expands to `a , (b , a) star`, so your parser as-is is saying "give me one character separated by commas".

It's not very readable, but this does what you want:

```
((($, asParser not , #any asParser) ==> [:nodes | nodes second])
  plus flatten delimitedBy: $, asParser
```

The first clause says "parse anything that isn't a comma". So given `'12,24'` you get `#('12' $, '24')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(#word asParser plus flatten separatedBy: $, asParser) 
     ==> [:nodes| nodes copyWithout: $, ]
```

I hope I understood what you wanted

Comment: Yes, the only problem with that one is that if the word contains any non alphabetical character that would break the parsing no?

Comment: Yes, it does. I was just resembling your example. You need to specify what you really need to parse. If it is everything you might be better off with $, asParser negate that Sean suggested